# How does a serial driver get attached with a tty port

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver, uart, tty

I am looking at Linux sample UART driver code here

https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/blob/master/tty/tiny_serial.c

Below is snipped from the code where UART driver is sending data to the tty port

```c
static void tiny_timer(unsigned long data)
{
    struct uart_port *port;
    struct tty_struct *tty;
    struct tty_port *tty_port;

    port = (struct uart_port *)data;
    if (!port)
        return;
    if (!port->state)
        return;
    tty = port->state->port.tty;
    if (!tty)
        return;

    tty_port = tty->port;

    /* add one character to the tty port */
    /* this doesn't actually push the data through unless tty->low_latency is set */
    tty_insert_flip_char(tty_port, TINY_DATA_CHARACTER, 0);

    tty_flip_buffer_push(tty_port);

    /* resubmit the timer again */
    timer->expires = jiffies + DELAY_TIME;
    add_timer(timer);

    /* see if we have any data to transmit */
    tiny_tx_chars(port);
}
```

However, what I am not clear about, looking at the code, is how is the coupling between UART port and tty port ever established. Is that something that has to be configured manually in Linux?

Comment: You have find an example from "Linux Driver Development" book. Have you read the book before asking about meaning of the example?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I am aware the snippet is from the LDD Book and yes I have read the book. Couldn't find answer to this in the book.

Comment: Funny, the function you put here as a code snippet has no answer to your question.

Comment: @0andriy yeah just wanted to show how the data was sent from serial driver to the tty port. But yeah it doesn't have an answer to my question. Also I looked at the rest of the code, and couldn't find much there either.

Comment: So, and reading *tiny_init()* didn't help?

Comment: @0andriy nah tiny_init didn't help

Comment: Strange. It's exactly the function which keeps an answer to your question. Just need to dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

In userspace the tty is treated as a file. So in this example the opened file descriptor is the uart port
https://github.com/guu1/serial-communitation-rs232

since from the termios functions used in userspace, they say in the man page

> The termios functions describe a general  terminal  interface  that  is
>   provided to control asynchronous communications ports.

Im not familiar with device drivers but from what i've looked it seems that instead of using functions like open() and write() to send and receive data, you use functions from the uart_core.h, uart_ops pointer

Quote from : https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6331

> One of the more interesting variables in this structure is the struct uart_ops pointer, which defines a list of functions that the serial core uses to call back into the port-specific serial driver.

Hope this helps